# How to Dynamically Configure Tenant Database Connection in Laravel 5.6 with Hyn 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, multi-tenant

I am using Hyn multi-tenancy v5.1 with Laravel v5.6 and have encountered an issue with setting up tenant-specific database connections.

I have customized the MariaDB query inside the Hyn package to handle database and user creation for each tenant by creating custom files, service Providers. My Custom MariaDB file as follow:

```
public function created(Created $event, array $config, Connection $connection): bool
    {
        $create = function ($connection) use ($config) {
            return $connection->statement("CREATE DATABASE `{$config['database']}`");
        };
        $createUser = function ($connection) use ($config) {
            return $connection->statement("CREATE USER `{$config['username']}`@'{$config['host']}' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '{$config['password']}'");
        };
        $grant = function ($connection) use ($config) {
            return $connection->statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `{$config['database']}`.* TO `{$config['username']}`@'{$config['host']}'");
        };

        return $connection->system()->transaction(function (IlluminateConnection $connection) use ($create, $createUser, $grant) {
            return $create($connection) && $createUser($connection) && $grant($connection);
        });
    }
```

This setup successfully creates a new tenant. However, I'm facing an issue with the error message: "Database [tenant] not configured."

I resolved this by adding a tenant connection array in config/database.php:

```
'tenant' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql'),
            'host' => '',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Issue:
While this fixes the immediate error, I am unsure how to dynamically populate the host, database, username, and password fields for each tenant's connection.

Question:
How can I dynamically set the database connection details (database, username, password) for each tenant in a Hyn 5.1 multi-tenant Laravel application?
Is there a standard or recommended approach within Hyn 5.1 for handling this dynamic configuration?
Any guidance or examples of handling dynamic database connections in a multi-tenant Laravel application using Hyn 5.1 would be greatly appreciated.